# How to avoid the splitting of a string when converting to set?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I am trying to convert a string to a set containing that string. How can I do this without splitting?

when I write:

```
set("abc")
```

the result is:

> {'a','b','c'}

but I want it to be:

> {"abc"}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Doku `set(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) will create a set of each element of an iterable - strings **are** iterable - hence you create a set of the characters of the string.

If you want whole strings, use

```
k = {"mystring",}
```

or

```
k = set( ["mystring"] ) # wrap your string into another iterable
```